# How to initiate touchscreen on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, touchscreen

I have a menu that uses hover to display submenus on a desktop. It seems with touchscreen devices the menu focus doesn't get initiated until after another element is touched (focused) first. When I touch the menu item to display the submenu, the menu item shows selected but the submenu doesn't display. If I take the focus off by touching another page element, such as an image or form field, and then touch the menu item a second time, the submenu works as expected. It will also work if I focus on a form element first and then the submenu. I have :hover, :focus, and :active all in my CSS but it seems to ignore the first focus/active. Is there a JQuery method to force the touchscreen device to initiate focus as soon as the page loads? Is there another solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, depending on css status is not enough to do what you are looking for here. It will either only work on desktops or only on mobile. Instead I would use the javascript ontouchstart event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) for this.

Assuming your css looks something like this:

```
.your-hoverable-class:hover  .submenu{
    display: block;
}
```

You can move that :hover state onto a class of its own (.is-hovered), like:

```
.your-hoverable-class.is-hovered .submenu{
    display: block;
}
```

Then you can perform the state toggling like this with Javascript (ES6)

```
const hoverableElem = document.querySelector('.your-hoverable-class');
hoverableElem.addEventListener('touchstart',(event)=>{
    event.target.classList.toggle('is-hovered')
});
```

Now the user can "tap" on that element if they are using a mobile device. the :hover css works quite well with mouse, so you may want to keep the :hover toggling as it is too. Otherwise, you can just use the onmouseover and onmouseout events like above if you want to stick to a pure javascript solution.